# Windows Command Line - Changing a file modified timestamp to an earlier datetime

Tags: windows, command-line, file-attributes

in windows command line i can use the following to change the timestamp of a file to the current datetime:

```
copy /b filename.ext +,,
```

what i need is a way to set the timestamp to a previous datetime (-1 day, -1 week etc)

is this possible?

What i typically do in linux is this:

```
touch -d "$(date -R -r filename) - 2 hours" filename
```

But i need this for windows command line, not powershell or any other alternative.

Comment: You could do it programmatically but I don't think there are any in-box tools to do it.

Comment: Set the time on the machine, then execute the same command.

Answer (score 2):

In Powershell, this works:

```
(gci)[1].LastWriteTimeUtc = (New-Object datetime 2013,12,31)
```

Comment: What is `(gci)[1]`?

Comment: GCI is alias to Get-ChildItem. It returns an array of files. [1] is the index of the file. You can use any other method to locate the file object of the file you need.

Answer (score 1):

In the end i used the windows port for Gnu:

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/

This example changes the timestamp for all files in a folder:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %i in ('dir "C:\Data\*" /s /b') do ("GnuWin32\Touch.exe" -t 1003141400 "%i")
```

or in a batch script:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir "C:\Data\*" /s /b') do ("GnuWin32\Touch.exe" -t 1003141400 "%%i")
```